# Attribution not showing up on google map

Tags: javascript, mobile, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

So I noticed today that the Google attribution that is suppsoed to be with the map isn't showing up. Is there an easy way for me to put that on the map somewhere manually?

The map is being built using the Javascript v3 api. We're using html5/javascript, jquery and jquery mobile to build the content which apps on iOS and android running phone gap.

```
var myOptions = {
        center: currentLocation,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        panControl: false
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], myOptions);
```

Thats how I'm setting up my map.

Edit: Found it! The first time I inspected the elements of the page I couldn't find the content for the attribution info but I found it this morning. It seems something else was setting the heigh of my map div which was pushing the copyright info of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way to optionally get rid of the Google attribution in Maps API v3.

If it's just not appearing, that might be a bug in the Maps API. I wouldn't worry about it. Google will fix it if they care deeply about the attribution.

If you really think it's something you're doing and not a bug in the API, post some code and maybe someone can figure out what's up.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't look like I'm anything wrong/strange with my request to google.

@Trott


`var myOptions = {
            center: currentLocation,
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            panControl: false
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(element[0], myOptions);
`